# How to host or stream video uploaded in google drive using google drive api

Tags: php, rest, api, google-drive-api

I am working on web-application where i need to stream video uploaded in google drive via google drive api. I have created service account to upload file, view files, and give permission. rather I gave permission to share file's at the particular domain, I am trying to access the file from subdomain as follow's. Here as example i am taking w3school.com to give access to stream video.
Following are my code's to give permission for domain:
  **I have also tried to give permission to email then video is played successfully **

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing

 $domainPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
        'type' => 'domain',
        'role' => 'reader',
        'domain' => 'w3schools.com'
    ));
    $request = $driveService->permissions->create(
        $fileId, $domainPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
    $batch->add($request, 'domain');
 $results = $batch->execute();
```

To get Weblink to stream video is as follow's ::

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw5e4zLE5mLv9lYob';

$argument = array(
                  "fields"=>"webViewLink",
                  );
  $file = $service->files->get($fileId,  $argument);

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($file);

it give's webviewlink as follow's 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw5e4zLE5mLv9lYob/view?usp=drivesdk

Now to stream video example html code is like this 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxxxxx5mLv9lYob/view?usp=drivesdk" type="video/mp4">
</video>


</body>
</html>`
```

I'm unable to play this video in my subdomain or main domain,
eg: webaccess.w3schools.com or w3schools.com

what can be possible error's in the process.
Please help Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue is due to Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB). So in your case, how about using `webContentLink` instead of `webViewLink`? It's like below URL.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxx5mLv9lYob&export=download
```

When your HTML is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxx5mLv9lYob&export=download" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

- **In this case, the video file is required to be shared. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Files of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Ashutosh Eve Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.